# MS Access database returns multiple entries for same person with more than one child

Tags: duplication, ms-access-2007

I know this is a very basic question, but I've watched about six Access database videos and still can't find the answer.  I'm a volunteer creating a membership database for a church in MS Access.  The children are in a table separate from their parents.  When I query the two tables for the data which I will then use in a Word mail merge, if a person has more than one child, that person will have more than one entry in the query results.

- How do I return just one entry for a parent with more than one child?
- Is it a Grouping function?

This is a basic question, for say a customer database, where a customer has more than one order, but I cannot find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: It can be a grouping issue (and it sounds more like a join issue to be honest), but we won't know until you show us some example data (names changed to protect the innocent, of course). Could you show us what the two tables you are referring to look like?